# change div content with one of 3 other divs?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 links, and a container div with an image. When I click a links I want to change the image with one of 3 divs containing 3 different videocodes?

So if I click on link one, then change the image to videocode 1.

What is the best way of doing that? appendTo, replaceWith or what - with jquery.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't realy understand it, can you explain it better?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<a href="image1.jpg">Link 1</a>
<a href="image2.jpg">Link 2</a>

<img id="image" src="image1.jpg" />

$('a').click(function() {
  $('#image').src($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

Another solution:

```
<a href="#image1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#image2">Link 2</a>

<div id="container">
  <img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" />
  <img id="image2" src="image2.jpg" />
</div>

$('a').click(function() {
  $('#container img').hide();
  $('img'+$(this).attr('href')).show();
  return false;
});
```

---

Based on your comment, something like this should do the trick:

```
<a href="#videocode1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#videocode1">Link 2</a>

<div id="container">
  <img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" />
  <div id="videocode1">
    yadda
  </div>
  <div id="videocode2">
    yadda
  </div>
</div>

$('a').click(function() {
  $('#container img, #container div').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).show();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: No, I dont want to replace the image with another image, I want to replace the image with a div with videocode.

Comment: No, I cant get it to work.
And I test with this to:
$("#videocode1").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#videocode2").css("visibility","hidden");
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#image1').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).show();
  return false;
});
And the videocode divs are visible from the start?

Comment: just use $("#videocode1, #videocode2").hide(); or in your CSS, just add display:none;. Please stay away from visibility:hidden, unless you want just the contents to be hidden (but keep the space clear).